# Solve non-linear system in IntegerMod(2)

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math

I want to solve a non-linear system in the domain IntegerMod(2) with Matlab (MuPAD). I tried a simple example:

```
solve({ poly(a*b, [a, b], Dom::IntegerMod(2)) })
```

*Error: Can only solve linear systems over that field. [solvelib::domsolve]*

Any idea how to solve this?

One possible solution would be `a=0, b=0`, right?

Comment: If the number of variables `n` is small (lets say `n<20`), you can always resort to doing a brute-force search of all `2^n` possibilities.

Comment: @knedlsepp I actually did this for a bit more complex problem with `n=11`, but I assumed that there must be some smarter way using computer algebra system.

Comment: There can't be a **general** smart way to do this that doesn't involve a full space search. You will at least have to specify something about your function. Is it a polynomial equation? What's the degree and the number of variables? This is generally a hard problem for large `n`: [SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem)